# Trouble loading a library - HTSFilter

Tags: r, bioconductor, install.packages, hmisc

I am trying to open a library called HTSFilter. I was able to install the package without a problem using this code:

```
> install.packages("HTSFilter")
```

And got this message:

```
> package ‘HTSFilter’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

But then when I tried to open it:

```
> library(HTSFilter)
```

I got this error message:

```
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘HTSFilter’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Hmisc’
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply try `install.packages("Hmisc")` before running your code or before `install.packages("HTSFilter")`, because what this warning is telling you is that `Hmisc` package is not installed in your environment.

Sometimes, when loading packages, some dependencies are not automatically downloaded and installed. It may happen that `Hmisc` ask you for more packages, so...install them before `Hmisc`.

Comment: Okay, so I was able to install Hmisc successfully, but now when I tried to install HTSFilter, I got an error that says:

> Warning message:
package ‘HTSFilter’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

Comment: Checking the documentation of bioconductor, in order to download this package in R.3.6: https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/bioc/html/HTSFilter.html

Comment: If the problem persists (because you installed Bioconductor 3.11, because it comes by default), update R into version R.4. or install Bioconductor version 3.10. Here you may find more information about how to install Bioconductor (which containt HTSFilter) https://bioconductor.org/install/

Comment: I tried to update it to 3.10 using the code from bioconductor.org/install:

> if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
+     install.packages("BiocManager")
> BiocManager::install(version = "3.10")

And got this:

Bioconductor version 3.10 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: boot, class,
  KernSmooth, lattice, MASS, nlme, nnet, spatial, survival
Old packages: 'htmltools'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: a

Comment: I pressed "a"

>  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://repo.miserver.it.umich.edu/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/htmltools_0.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 692715 bytes (676 KB)
downloaded 676 KB

package ‘htmltools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

But then it still would not allow me to install the HTSFilter. Why would some of the packages not update?

Comment: I'll check this more in deep. What I suggest you is to upload your R software from 3.6.3 to 4.0.0 (unless you need a older version of R in terms of compatibility or specific functions). Then, try to install the package as you did in the beginning.
Bioconductor 3.11 is compatible with R 4.0.